# Unable to install Lotus Notes 8.5.3

Tags: software-installation, ibm-lotus-notes

```
mallikarjun@1W11:~/Documents/MSJ/SysAdmin/LN853/lotus_notes853_linuxUb_en$ sudo dpkg -i ibm-lotus-notes-8.5.3.i586.deb 
[sudo] password for mallikarjun: 
dpkg: regarding ibm-lotus-notes-8.5.3.i586.deb containing ibm-lotus-notes, pre-dependency problem:
 ibm-lotus-notes pre-depends on libgnomeprint2.2-0

dpkg: error processing ibm-lotus-notes-8.5.3.i586.deb (--install):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing ibm-lotus-notes
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ibm-lotus-notes-8.5.3.i586.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Use gdebi:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi ibm-lotus-notes-8.5.3.i586.deb
```

Gdebi is a simple package manager that uses `apt-get` power to find and install the dependencies of a single package.