# E:unable to locate package libgnome-desktop-2-17:i386

Tags: ibm-lotus-notes

I am trying to install IBM Notes 9.0 on Ub16.04-64Bit(Xenial) and thus was trying to install some deprecated packages using command -

```
sudo apt-get install libgnome-desktop-2-17:i386.
```

It throws me the message

```
E:unable to locate package libgnome-desktop-2-17:i386
```

Please suggest me how to install this package on Ub16.04-64Bit.

IBM Notes 9.0 facing pre-dependency problem with

- libgnome-desktop-2
- libgnome-desktop-2-7
- libgnome-desktop-2-11
- libgnome-desktop-2-17
- libgnome-desktop-3-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install Lotus Notes 8.5.3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/442264/unable-to-install-lotus-notes-8-5-3)

Answer (score 0):

You can find Ubuntu packages from previous releases here:

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas/list?name=libgnome-desktop

You may also need to install gdebi, so that you can install any .deb files you download from the site, easily.